# Center background image on page within margins using eso-pic

Tags: latex

In my thesis I'm including already published papers. I've extracted pages as individual EPS files and I'm shrinking them so they fit on one page within the margins (`\pageScale`).

```
\hfill{}\includegraphics[scale=\pageScale]{Integrative-Theory-Associative/eps-pages/page-1}\hfill{}
```

While this works ok, the pages appear extremely small to fit in the margins. I'd like to increase the size of the graphics beyond the margins such that header and page number information would overlap with margins of the inserted pages.

eso-pic allows me to fill the whole page with my inserted pages, but the header and page number overlap with the text in the inserted pages:

```
\mbox{}
\AddToShipoutPictureBG*{
  \includegraphics{Integrative-Theory-Associative/pdf-pages/page-1.pdf}
}
\newpage
```

[image: Example Output]

I's like to scale down and centre the graphics on the page so they are as big as possible while text within the graphics is not behind the header and is within the margins.

I don't mind manually figuring out the right scale for graphics, but I can't figure how to place the centre of a smaller graphic in the centre of the margins. `\AtPageCenter`
 does not do what I expected, centre the centre of the graphic, not centre the lower left of the graphic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the example below I've used some of [`adjustbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/adjustbox)'s prowess to adjust included content:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,lipsum}% Just for this example
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[C]{This is some random header text}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{.4pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{eso-pic}

\newcommand{\pictureincenteroftextblock}[2][]{%
  \AddToShipoutPictureBG*{%
    \AtTextLowerLeft{%
      \raisebox{.5\textheight}{%
        \hspace*{.5\textwidth}%
        \makebox[0pt]{\includegraphics[max width=\textwidth,max height=\textheight,valign=c,#1]{#2}}%
      }%
    }%
  }%
}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-5]

\clearpage

\mbox{}% Just put something on this page.
\pictureincenteroftextblock{example-image-a}

\clearpage

\mbox{}% Just put something on this page.
\pictureincenteroftextblock{example-image-10x16}

\clearpage

\mbox{}% Just put something on this page.
\pictureincenteroftextblock{example-image-1x1}

\clearpage

\mbox{}% Just put something on this page.
\pictureincenteroftextblock{example-image-a4}

\end{document}
```

With the `[export]` option, `adjustbox` adds its key-values to [`graphicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx)'s `\includegraphics` options. Those I've used are `max width` and `max height` which will *shrink* the included image (or page from a PDF) if the width or height exceeds  these maxima while still maintaining the included image/page aspect ratio. Additionally, `valign=c` will `align` the content in a `v`ertically `c`entred fashion.

[`eso-pic`](http://ctan.org/pkg/eso-pic) is used to place the image in the background, starting at the lower-left part of the text block. Then, through standard spacing commands, it's raised into position (`\raisebox`) and shoved over (`\hspace`) to the centre of the text block. Finally the image is horizontally centred (`\makebox[0pt]`).

Comment: Thanks @Werner! I have two clarification questions: (a) I was unable to get the adjustbox package to work; the CTAN package contains adjustbox.dtx and adjustbox.ins but no adjustbox.sty, while latex reports: File `adjustbox.sty' not found. (b) As the pages I would like to insert have their own margins, I would like only the text part (inside the margins) to fit within the margins of my thesis. This means I should be able to supply a scaling factor that would allow the inserted pages to grow a little beyond the margins of the thesis. I'm not sure how to do this as I'm more using LyX than LaTeX.

Comment: @b..: When you install LyX, it asks you whether you want to download MiKTeX or whether you have an existing TeX distribution on your installed (like, for example, TeX Live). I'm assuming you downloaded MiKTeX at the time of installation. So, you need to use the [MiKTeX Package Manager/MPM](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55437/5764). From there you should be able to select to install [`adjustbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/adjustbox). Instead of the options I supplied, you can use `width=<len>` or `height=<len>` or `scale=<factor>`.

Comment: (a) I am running texlive (ubuntu precise) but no package does contains adjustbox. I ended up installing the files (and requirements) locally from https://www.tug.org/texlive//Contents/live/texmf-dist/tex/latex/adjustbox/. (b) I'm not sure what you mean in the context of your answer above, could you edit it? Ideally, the base size would be fitting in the margins (As above), and a scaling factor like 1.2 would be 20% larger than that base size.

Comment: replacing `\makebox[0pt]{\includegraphics[max width=\textwidth,max height=\textheight,valign=c,#1]{#2}}%` with `\makebox[0pt]{\includegraphics[scale=0.9,valign=c,#1]{#2}}%` seemed to do the trick. Thanks.